# io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: is showing while running 2 scenarios in 1 feature file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

```
Feature:Onboard User
    Scenario:Test whether Onboarding is successful
        Given User is on apploaded page
        When user clicks nextbutton link,navigates to upcoming onboard pages
        And Once all the onboard screens get over,loads the login page
        Then User successfully completes onboard screens

Feature: SignUp User
    Background: User is on Login page
    Scenario Outline: Test whether SignUp is successful
        Given Signup link Visibility
        When User clicks Signup link which navigates to SignUp page
        And Update <firstname>,<lastname>,<email>,<password>,<confirm password>,<phone number>and submit
        Then User successfully completes Signup and navigtes to SignIn page
        Examples:
            | firstname | lastname | email                      | password  | confirm password |
            | dona      | feble    | donafeble@gmail.com        | 123456    | 123456           |
            | riya      | mary     | riyamaryemmanuel@gmail.com | test@riya | test@riya        |
```

This is my feature file.
and i got error as follows-

```
[ERROR] initializationError(Runner.AppTest)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException:
Failed to parse resource at: file:///e:/LMS-cucumber-appium/src/test/resources/features/home.feature
(8:1): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ExamplesLine, #ScenarioLine, #RuleLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Feature: SignUp User'
(9:5): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ExamplesLine, #ScenarioLine, #RuleLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Background: User is on Login page'.
```

But when i run scenarios in seperate feature files,i dont have any errors.
Could anyone help me,to identify  the reason behind ?

Comment: Gherkin, the language in which feature files are written does not allow more than one feature per file.

Comment: Also your background should probably have some steps in it

Comment: Another general observation is that your steps are way too verbose. For example, the step `User clicks Signup link which navigates to SignUp page` should simply be `User clicks Signup link`. Even better, "signup" should be a parameter, like `User clicks "Signup" link` so that you could reuse this step definition to test clicking other links. When steps are too verbose, 1) They run the risk of not being too reusable, and 2) People writing test scenarios may run the chance to making a mistake that would cause the step definition not to be found. A short, concise step is always better.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark this link for future reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/

From the documentation:

> The first primary keyword in a Gherkin document must always be **Feature**, followed by a '**:**' and a short text that describes the feature.

Also:

> You can only have a single **Feature** in a .feature file.

As M.P. Korktanje indicated in the comments, you violated these rules by having two `Feature` blocks in a single `.feature` file.

To fix, copy and paste the scenarios under the first feature block and delete the second. Also, if you need to add more to your file, follow the linked instructions to format your scenarios properly to avoid future problems.

One last observation... `Background` is used in Cucumber to execute something before your scenarios. Read the [Background](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) section for correct usage. The main purpose is to eliminate repeating the initial steps in every scenario. For example, to test your web application, you may need to authenticate the user. This may be a good day to establish those steps as a prerequisite (background) for all the scenarios in the feature. This is not to be mistaken for the `Example` block, which is used to repeat (loop) the same scenario with different parameters; eliminating the need of duplicating just to repeat the same steps with different inputs.